# WhatsApp Web using CM12.1 often can't connect

Tags: cyanogenmod, whatsapp-messenger, connection-issues

I had CyanogenMod 12.1 on my Nexus 4 and after switching to the Sony Xperia Z3 I installed the newest nightly, too. On both phones I have trouble getting WhatsApp Web to work.

I can scan the QR code without problems but ~50 % of time the loading spinner on the website won't disappear. Removing the browsers in the app doesn't help and even removing the app's data and setting it up from scratch didn't change anything.

I have the same problems using 3G or WiFi and also in different WiFi networks (home/work).

Sometimes, the following exception appears in the LogCat

```
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.030 14060-14097/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.055 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.056 14060-14091/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.058 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.059 14060-14100/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.060 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.061 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2)
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4)
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:  Caused by: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17) 
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16) 
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1) 
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.a(m.java:2) 
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at org.whispersystems.jobqueue.m.run(m.java:4) 
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.Exception: delivery failed
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.a(bh.java:17)
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.messaging.bh.get(bh.java:16)
    10-09 14:32:11.062 14060-14101/com.whatsapp W/m:     at com.whatsapp.jobqueue.job.b.k(b.java:1)    enter preformatted text here
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and did two things at the same time to fix it (so not sure what the actual fix was)

1. Disable AdBlock filtering.
2. Hold phone in landscape to scan the QR code.